# Summing values for an overview

Tags: sql, mysql

I want get the time used for a case so I can create an overview.

The SELECT query for the cases looks like this:

```
SELECT bc.id, bc.title, bc.estimateCurrent FROM cases bc
```

For one case I can get the used time like this:

```
SELECT SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dateEnding, dateBeginning))) AS calculatedTime FROM timesheet WHERE `#case` = ?
```

How do I connect both so I have one value for the overview SELECT query? Basically I would want the table to look like this:

```
id|title|estimateCurrent|timeusedinsec
 1|case1|             20|    2000
 2|case2|             40|    2500
 3|case3|             70|       0
```

Is that possible? I didn't want to have a for each query on the php side which would result in several queries. Would a view help?

Comment: You called a column `#case`? That just feels icky...

Comment: It beats a column called '#' ;)

Comment: # are foreignkeys that way a key can be identified quickly I enjoy having it like this may be a stupid thing though :(

Comment: An "_id" suffix would be more conventional, and would avoid you having to quote the column name.

Comment: hmm interessting I will suggest this thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the timesheet column `#case` refers to bc.id, you could use a join like this:

```
SELECT 
    bc.id, bc.title, bc.estimateCurrent,
    SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(dateEnding, dateBeginning)))
FROM cases bc
JOIN timesheet ts on ts.`#case` = bc.id
GROUP BY bc.id, bc.title, bc.estimateCurrent
```

The GROUP BY defines how SUM() works. Here, it will make SUM() add up all rows with the same #case number.

Comment: awesome I was trying to figure this out really badly :D

Comment: You may want to consider the join type here as cases that no-one has yet worked on will not be visible with a natural join.

Comment: Is the GROUP BY with the different things really important? Would GROUP BY bc.id be enough?

Comment: Yes the GROUP BY clause must name all columns that are not aggregates or constants

Comment: LEFT JOIN is same as JOIN, LEFT is the default.  It's a best practice to specify every non-aggregated column in the GROUP BY clause.  But MySQL is one of the few databases that does not enforce this, so GROUP BY bc.id would be enough.

Comment: INNER JOIN is the default is most DBs